# J Developer 32-bit Error when installing( ERROR Launch:No such file or directory)

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I downloaded JDeveloper from Oracle web site for 64 bit

I have a problem and couldn't install it.

It gives the following error

```
---------------------------
ERROR
---------------------------
ERROR Launch:No such file or directory 

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the way to solve the problem.

JDeveloper needs to access the registry, so you need to run the setup as an administrator in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of Jdevelopper Studio must be autorized, for that you execute the installator as administrator. All after verifiying if the JDK is correctly cofigured to the environnement variale

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the File and Then choose Run As Administrator....just it

Comment: Is your answer actually complete?? it seems to end strangely.

Answer (score -1):

after you update your operating system you can right click on the installation file and run as administrator
first you can check your jdk version and compatibility with OS